# How to pass variable from comprehension to function?

Tags: function, list-comprehension

I have been trying to solve this comprehension task, but I can't figure out how to pass the variable from the comprehension to the function. How do I do this?

```html
words = ['whatever', 'anything', 'bla']

def words_starting_with_character(char):
    return [word for word in words if word[0] == char]

def alphabet():
    return string.ascii_lowercase

def dictionary():
    return {[letter for letter in alphabet()]: words_starting_with_character(letter)}
```

Comment: Could you explain more about the functionality of the code? What is the expected output of the code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.